# Prove that two groups for elliptic curves are isomorphic

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-geometry, finite-groups, elliptic-curves, group-isomorphism

I was asked to calculate all the possible groups for elliptic curves and their order in $\mathbb{F}_5$.  There are $p^2-p$ groups that respect $\Delta \neq 0$, so there are $20$ groups.

Some of them may be isomorphic. I have to look for the ones with the same order.

For example: are the ones defined by $x^3+4x+2$ and $x^3+4x+3$ isomorphic?
The points of the first groups are $(3,1), (3,4), (\infty, \infty)$, for the second group are $(2,2), (2,3), (\infty, \infty)$

How do I check if they are isomorphic or not?

Comment: As the answer says there is nothing to prove.

Comment: Other examples over $\Bbb F_5$ can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/605343/structure-of-cf-5-from-rational-points-on-elliptic-curves?rq=1). The list is not very difficult in the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you have two groups of order three which means they are isomorphic as there only is one group of order $3$ up to isomorphism.

Comment: This was actually an example. I have also around 5 groups of order 6 and I don't know how to check if they are isomorphic

Comment: Groups of order 6 are either cyclic (therefore also abelian) or isomorphic to $S_3$.  So you could check whether they are abelian or not.

Comment: Just to make sure: That means all of them are isomorphic as groups as elliptic curves have the structure of abelian groups.